# ajuda com SQL Nvarchar

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Olá,

Tive alguns problemas com um código no `SELECT`...

exemplo:

```
SELECT dados FROM banco WHERE CPF='$CPF' // com o código assim estava dando alguns erros pois o bd era em SQL e o Servidor windows.
```

A solução foi:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST([dados] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS dados FROM dbo.banco WHERE CPF='$CPF;
```

Eu queria saber se tem outra solução mais simples que não precise de um código tão extenso...

tipo, se eu quiser detalhar os campos da tabela e  utilizar 4 campos, ele só funciona se eu colocar os `CAST` onde é `nVARCHAR`.
Obs: eu não posso alterar no banco de `nVARCHAR` para apenas `VARCHAR`.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Seria legal informar o erro.

Comment: Qual driver você está usando para conectar ao SQL Server no PHP? Acho que você precisa configurar o tamanho máximo permitido para textos ([referência](https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/sql-server-php-truncating-text/)), caso contrário os valores são truncados.

Comment: Não há erro amigo, só queria uma solução melhor... pq o código fica muito extenso...

Comment: "com o código assim estava dando alguns erros" (`SELECT dados FROM banco WHERE CPF='$CPF'`). Há erro ou não há? Se não há, qual o problema de usar assim (sem CAST)?

Comment: É que fazendo a consulta com o CAST exige muito da memória utilizada pelo php(Acho que é isso) e em alguns casos como o código fica muito extenso, acaba apresentando o seguinte "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2184 bytes) in /home/storage/6/c4/26/amb8/public_html/user/dados.php on line 105" ...
Então eu queria um cód mais limpo também, eu entendo o básico de php por isso estou me complicando um pouco para explicar rsrs ...

Comment: Continuo não entendendo por que você não usa `SELECT dados FROM banco WHERE CPF='$CPF'`

Comment: Qual driver você para conectar mssql, sqlsrv, PDO?

Comment: Caffé usar o cód desse jeito não funfa... por causa que no SQL os campos estão em nVARCHAR e não apenas em VARCHAR...
rray estou usando "mssql" ... 
O atendente da Locaweb me passou a seguinte informação:
"Você deverá então, aprimorar seu select, que como pode-se notar faz diversas conversões e puxa diversos registros, causando assim a exaustão da memória do Php."
E ai me passou uma solução que vou tentar e jajá eu falo pra vocês se deu certo...

Comment: @Ursones *"no SQL os campos estão em nVARCHAR e não apenas em VARCHAR"* - isso não é motivo para `SELECT dados FROM banco WHERE CPF='$CPF'` não funcionar. O que falta é dizer qual comportamento indesejado ou erro foi obtido com esta query de modo que tenha sido obrigado a usar conversões (CAST); assim nós ajudaríamosa resolver o problema real em vez do problema causado por uma conversão estranha (o tipo TEXT é deprecated no MSSQL). Consegui explicar?

Comment: @Caffé Verdade amigo, vlw a explicação, no final alterei o php.ini pq a configuração não estava autorizando o uso do mssql... `mssql.compatability_mode = Off`, mudei para `On` E não precisei usar `CAST`... Vlw pelas dicas e paciência comigo haha...

Comment: @Ursones Sem problemas! De nada.

Comment: @Ursones, coloque o procedimento que você fez como resposta, assim pode ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema :).

Comment: Ok e Obrigado a todos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No fina das contas a solução estava no arquivo php.ini, mas por que?

Ao fazer o `$query = mssql_query("SELECT SEXO, NOME, RG...) WHERE...` dava um erro pois a utilização do parâmetro `MSSQL` estava desligada no arquivo "php.ini", fuçando no arquivo achei a seguinte linha `mssql.compatability_mode = Off` alterei para `On`, ai resolveu, precisei usar o `CAST` apenas em alguns campos `nVarChar(max)` que pois dava erro.

Acho que é só isso e espero ajudar alguém que encontra-se na mesma situação.